# FBSDKAppInviteDialog doesn't load list of friends

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, uiwebview, fbsdkappinvitecontent

`UIWebView` page that was opened by showing `FBSDKAppInviteDialog` doesn't load list of friends as usual, but stops either at an empty page state or at the infinite loading indicator state.

```
    let text = "invite text"
    content.appLinkURL = URL(string: "valid_url_to_fb_me")!
    content.promotionText = text
    content.promotionCode = "\(code)"
    
    let dialog = FBSDKAppInviteDialog()
    dialog.fromViewController = self.viewController
    dialog.content = content
    dialog.delegate = self
    dialog.show()
```

And `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate` methods were not called.

This behaviour was not reproducible a week ago.

iOS Simulator 10.2, same behaviour on the iOS 10.2.1 on real device the iPhone 5S and iPad mini 9.2.

Facebook SDK - 4.15.1

**Thanks in advance for any help or sugestions.**

[image: Empty Screen state]
[image: Loading indicatator state]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the bug is on Facebook's side:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/721787828000962/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought in the same way, just haven't found a proof.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook bug mentioned by BoygeniusDexter (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/721787828000962/) is actually on Android not iOS.

Are you using the deprecated UIActionSheet to open FBSDKAppInviteDialog?  If so removing UIActionSheet is your solution: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/172327909915305/

Comment: Initial bug was reported by Android, but the issue was on the Facebook service side. So as you can see in the later comments same bug appeared on iOS clients as well.